# Can't access to "Online Accounts" with system settings

Tags: gwibber, online-accounts

I tried to access Online Accounts with the System Settings but it's just not there... I succeed to open it via terminal, but how can it be back with all the other System Settings icon?

Answer (score 2):

It's a known bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-online-accounts/+bug/950352

There is a suggestion there:
open the file

```
/usr/share/applications/gnome-online-accounts-panel.desktop
```

you'll need to be sudo in order to do it. Then find the line:

```
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;
```

and change it to

```
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
```

Save&Exit. That's what did it for me, your online accounts icon should be back in the system settings panel.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely there, in system settings in the top "personal" section.  If you still can't find it, open the Unity dash by pressing <kbd>super</kbd> and type "Online Accounts" without the quotes into the search.